# How can I make my application to link libraries independent of its location?

Tags: makefile, shared-libraries

I have built a shared library (i.e `libabc.so`) and an executable (i.e `myapp`) which uses my shared library. I have placed both the shared library and my executable in my filesystem but when I run my executable it gives me the following error

```
error while loading shared libraries: <target_lib_path>/<mylib>.so cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory.
```

Now my dev environment is I have a different target filesystem which is placed at `~/targetfs` after building my shared library I am installing it in `~/targetfs/usr/local/abc/lib`. During linking my application I give it

```
LDFLAGS += -L~/targetfs/usr/local/abc/lib
```

My application builds fine. But when I run my application in an environment where `~/targetfs` is my filesystem, then my application complains 
error while loading shared libraries:

```
/home/user/targetfs/usr/local/abc/lib/libabc.so: can not open shared object file. No such file or directory exist.
```

Now, of course the path my application is searching for the shared library that does not exist, but I want my application to be independent of this path, rather it should look for my shared library in `/lib`, `/usr/lib`, `/usr/local/lib` or `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` location.

How can I make my application to link libraries independent of its location?

Makefiles for my shared library & application is given below.

-------------- Shared library makefile. (Omitting un-necessary info)

```
CC              = $(CROSS_COMPILE)gcc
CFLAGS          = -Wall -shared -fpic
LDFLAGS         = -Xlinker --gc-sections --allow-shlib-undefined
LIBRARY         = libabc.so
OBJ_DIR         = obj
SRC_DIR         = src
CHK_DIR_EXISTS  = test -d
MKDIR           = mkdir -p

# Project Source Files
C_SOURCES += $(SRC_DIR)/abc.c
OBJECTS   += $(OBJ_DIR)/abc.o
INCLUDES  += -Iinc                               
$(LIBRARY): $(OBJECTS)
    @echo ""
    @echo "Linking..." $(LIBRARY)
    @$(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) -o $(OBJ_DIR)/$(LIBRARY)
```

---------- Application Makefile (Omitting un-necessary info)

```
LDFLAGS += $(TARGETFS)/usr/local/abc/lib/libabc.so           \
       -lpthread -lrt
```

Any thoughts what's missing in my Makefiles.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can ask the linker to put multiple search paths into the binary. You introduce those search paths with the -Wl,rpath=... option.

```
gcc -o abc abc.c 
-L~/targetfs/usr/local/abc/lib 
-labc 
-Wl,-rpath=/usr/local/abc/lib 
-Wl,-rpath=...
-Wl,-rpath=...
```

Comment: May make sense to mention `$ORIGIN` as well.