# Compiling .c source file and .so dynamic library together

Tags: c, gcc, shared-libraries

I have been trying to compile a C source file (driver.c) with a main method with a dynamic library (libhello.so) file that has all the implementations of the functions used in the main method.

I make the .so file with

```
gcc -shared -o libhello.so -fPIC hello.c
```

It compiles fine and returns the file in the directory as expected.

Then I try to compile the driver.c file with the dynamic library libhello.so with

```
gcc driver.c libhello.so -o driver
```

It compiles without complaint and the issue happens when I try to run the executable "driver". I get the follwing error:

```
./driver: error while loading shared libraries: libhello.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I'm confused because the file is literally right there in the directory of which it is being compiled in. Can someone explain this for me?

Comment: give ./libhello.so while compiling with driver.c because it's a user defined library. Have you copied libhello.so  into /lib directory ?

Comment: I compiled with ./libhello.c and it worked perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [error while loading shared libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9482984/error-while-loading-shared-libraries)

Comment: "I compiled with ./libhello.c" this of course doesn't use libhello.so you have built

Comment: @user3629249 it is perfectly ok to say libhello.so, it does exactly the same as -L. -lhello.

Comment: @n.m.,  in my experience, just listing the library full name is acceptable, but common practice is to drop the `lib` and drop the `.so`.   Note: I moved my comment to an answer

Answer (score 1):

Actually you do not dynamically link with libhello.so. You need -l option.
-lhello
You can check dependencies with ldd driver (your exec).

Answer (score -1):

regarding:

```
gcc driver.c libhello.so -o driver
```

is not correct.

It should be similar to:

```
gcc driver.c -o driver -L. -lhello
```

of course, there should be a header file that contains all the prototypes, etc for the library libhello.so

That header file typically would be named: hello.h so the final compile+link statement would be:

```
gcc driver.c -o driver -I. -L. -lhello <<< edited
```

I made a misstate,  The last line, the '-I' parameter should list the directory for the header file, not the header file name

Comment: @n.m.,  To try it, suggest you post the contents of the `driver.c` and the `libhello.c`  AND the contents of a header file for the `libhello.c`  Then I can try it.

Comment: The content may be arbitrary. It's totally irrelevant. All of the information needed to reproduce the problem is present in the question.

Comment: actually, the content is relevant.  Especially the availability of the prototypes for the functions in the `libhello.so` file.

Comment: No, this is not true. When a library isn't there, the insides of the library are irrelevant. You have not tried this. The answer is wrong and misleading.

Comment: @n.m., if this answer is wrong, then quit commenting upon it and write your own answer.

Comment: This question already has an answer and I have voted to close it as a duplicate.